# Como faço um reload somente na janela modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3

Estou utilizando modal do Bootstrap e queria que ao fechar e abrir o novo modal as informações fossem resetadas.

Eu tenho um `form` dentro do modal, contendo `select`, `textarea`, `input`.
Mas ao abrir o modal da linha de baixo, se o usuário modificou algo no primeiro modal ele aparece no modal da linha abaixo.
 eu utilizei o comando abaixo

```
$('#myModalpv').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    location.reload();
})
```

Mas ele faz na página toda, eu gostaria que fizesse o reload, volta-se o modal no estado inicial, quando o usuário abrir os próximos modal.

Usei também o código abaixo:

```
  $('#myModalpv').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#form2 input select').each(function() {
          $(this).val('');
      });
  });
```

Limpou as informações mas não retornou ao estado inicial do meu modal.

Comment: Que informações precisamente?

Comment: Você quer fazer reload ou limpar campos? E é só na janela do modal?

Comment: Correto Jorge, eu tenho um <form> dentro do modal com input, textarea, select, mas quando eu abro o modal da linha abaixo ele ainda contem as informações que foram modificadas quando abriu o modal anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer limpar todo o conteúdo do modal?

Se for isso, pode remover o conteúdo do body.

Por ex:

```
$('#myModalpv').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 $(".modal-body").html("");
})
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não era isso que eu precisava, mas achei muito interessante.

Answer (score 0):

Meus dois centavos:

- 1) Você deveria ter uma função que cria o modal do zero conforme a sua necessidade. Dessa forma sempre que precisar você pode montar um novo do zero, com o estado inicial;
- 2) eu acho que `$('#form2 input select')` seleciona todos os selects *dentro de inputs* dentro do form 2. Talvez o que você queira mesmo é algo como:

```
$("#form2").find("input, select").each(function () { // Atenção à vírgula
    //aqui você limpa.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for campos de formulario, voce pode simplesmente resetar

```
$('form').reset();
```

Pode utilizar assim tambem...

```
   $('form').each(function(){
  $("#select").val($("#select option:first").val());
```

});

https://jsbin.com/xihotu/1/edit?html,css,js,output